# Vox populi badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Today I have received vox populi badge, but I haven't used maximum 40 votes today nor yesterday nor in last 7 days and I think I have never done it. So why I received it?

Comment: This happened to me as well.

Comment: Me ... wait, I have it and I actually deserve it. Nevermind... `:-)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.